# regex to strip leading zeros treated as string

Tags: java, regex

I have numbers like this that need leading zero's removed.

Here is what I need:

`00000004334300343` -> `4334300343`

`0003030435243` -> `3030435243`

I can't figure this out as I'm new to regular expressions. This does not work:

```
(^0)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need quantifier:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^0+", "");
```

It replaces 1 or more occurrences of 0 (that is what `+` quantifier is for. Similarly, we have `*` quantifier, which means 0 or more), at the beginning of the string (that's given by caret - `^`), with empty string.

Comment: @HorseVoice Possibly post the shared link?

Comment: @HorseVoice but works in Java: http://ideone.com/TblPQ7 and isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @RohitJain can u plz explain ur answer so I can learn and vote u up plz?

Comment: @KickButtowski Which character are you talking about, that needs escaping? `^0` will only match 1 `0`, not more than that.

Comment: @RohitJain      what do u mean by mentioning empty string in ur answer? why didn't use escape character in ur regex?

Comment: @KickButtowski Dude, seriously that part doesn't need more explanation than that. Did you go through the `String` class docs? See how `replaceAll()` method works? I guess you'll get fair idea after that.

Comment: @KickButtowski `(^0)` didn't work because this regex can match only one `0` placed at start of the string. What OP wants is to match more than one `0` placed at start. This can be done by `*` quantifier which means that element described before it can appear zero or more times. Also which characters do you think should be escaped and why?

Comment: The regex should be `^0+` not `^0*` as the second regex will be matched for any string and do empty replacement.

Comment: @RohitJain this method fails if the number has a fraction like `000.123` it becomes `.123` it should be `0.123`

Answer (score 17):

Accepted solution will fail if you need to get "0" from "00". This is the right one:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^0+(?!$)", "");
```

`^0+(?!$)` means match one or more zeros if it is not followed by end of string.

Thank you to the commenter - I have updated the formula to match the description from the author.

Comment: this method fails with the numbers like `000001230000` it gives the output `1230`

Comment: The answer has been updated to reflect the correct regex. It was missing the "^" symbol from the replaceAll formula, but the Author has it in the description/explanation of the formula. I assume it was a miss/typo. Thanks, Mohsen for pointing it out.

Comment: When using strong-mode, you might want to use this:

str = str.replaceAll(RegExp("^0+(?!$)"), "");

Answer (score 5):

If you know input strings are all containing digits then you can do:

```
String s = "00000004334300343";
System.out.println(Long.valueOf(s));
// 4334300343
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/KwR3aP)

By converting to `Long` it will automatically strip off all leading zeroes.

Comment: so. it ignores the zeros?

Comment: Yes it does, check linked demo also.

Comment: for others answers, do not we need escape charcter \\?

Comment: There is not special character to escape in regex

Answer (score 4):

Another solution (might be more intuitive to read)

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^0+", "");
```

`^` - match the beginning of a line
0+ - match the zero digit character one or more times

A exhausting list of pattern you can find here [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: can u explain ur answer plz?

Answer (score 3):

`\b0+\B` will do the work.  See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP3iB2/1)  `\b` anchors your match to a word boundary, it matches a sequence of one or more zeros `0+`, and finishes not in a word boundary (to not eliminate the last `0` in case you have only `00...000`)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I think the best way to do this is actually

```
str = str.replaceAll("(^0+)?(\d+)", "$2")
```

The reason I suggest this is because it splits the string into two groups. The second group is *at least* one digit. The first group matches 1 or more zeros at the start of the line. However, the first group is optional, meaning that if there are no leading zeros, you just get all of the digits. And, if `str` is *only* a zero, you get exactly one zero (because the second group must match at least one digit).

So if it's any number of 0s, you get back exactly one zero. If it starts with any number of 0s followed by any other digit, you get no leading zeros. If it starts with any other digit, you get back exactly what you had in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex to strip leading zeros is

```
str = str.replaceAll("^0+", "");
```

This regex will match `0` character in quantity of `one and more` at the string beginning.
There is not reason to worry about `replaceAll` method, as regex has `^` (begin input) special character that assure the replacement will be invoked only once.

**Ultimately**  you can use Java build-in feature to do the same:

```
String str = "00000004334300343";
long number = Long.parseLong(str);
// outputs 4334300343
```

The leading zeros will be stripped for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "0600974";
str = str.replaceAll("\\b0+(\\d+)\\b", "$1");
```

This is a better match, Code is in java, to use in other languages you can replace double slash with one `e.g "\\b" will be "\b" and "\\d" will be "\d"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and proper solution.

```
str = str.replaceAll(/^0+/g, "");
```

Global Flag `g` is required when using `replaceAll` with regex.

Answer (score 0):

In `Azure Synapse`, the expression would be this:

```
regexReplace(ColumnName, "^0+", "")

000000502842 will equal 502842
```